# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I am new to xcode kindly help me to correct the error my code is below,

```
-(void)XYZ:(NSString *)id1
{
    id2 = [id1 intValue];
    [self Vehicles:id2];

}

-(NSArray *)Vehicles:(NSInteger) id2
{

    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/vehiclelist.php?uid=%d&format=json",id2];
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *results = [json valueForKey:@"posts"];
    return results;
}
```

And i pass the id value from the login vied controller the code is,

```
if(stat!=0&&id2!=0&&[Username length]!=0&&[Password length]!=0)
{
    Services *loc = [[Services alloc] initWithNibName:@"Services" bundle:nil]; 
    loc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    loc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:loc animated:YES completion:Nil];
    MyVchicle *about = [[MyVchicle alloc]  initWithNibName:@"MyVchicle" bundle:nil];
    about.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    about.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:about animated:YES completion:Nil];
    [loc XYZ:id1];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to pass data from one controller to another ?

Comment: yes I pass the id1 value from one view controller to another

Comment: @Ragul Please format and indent your code properly.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo yes i did it but still am facing the same error

Comment: @Ragul It doesn't matter. You have to indent your code properly if you want other people to be able to read your code.

Comment: ya thank you I will follow it in my feauture questions

Answer (score 0):

For sending data from one ViewController to another, follow these steps :

1. Declare a variable in your DestinationViewController.
2. Connect a segue from your SourceViewController to your DestinationViewController.
3. Now in your SourceViewController, write this function :

> ```
>  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
>         {
>         DestinationViewController *destController = [segue destinationViewController];
>         destController.varName = @"passThisValue";
>         }
> ```

4. The above function declares your destinationViewController and assigns a value to the variable of the destinationViewController that we declared above.

This should get you going. Hope this helps.

You can refer to this link.

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Sorry am very new to xcode can u guide me a demo for pass the value  & i am not using the storyboard. Thank you

Comment: Yes the same way am also used for passing but it shows error

Comment: Can you show the error log ? Maybe that could help on identifying the problem.

Comment: The value is sucessfuly passed but the error comes only when it try to move to the next page.

Comment: I am not getting more out of it now since you are not using a storyboard. Btw, just give it a try with a storyboard. That might work out in your case. Will post some links if they are helpful. Keep trying.

Comment: Sorry now am in the middle of the project so i cant use the storyboard

Comment: Lets see. I will have a look into it. Need some time for it as I always work around with storyboards. Keep trying.

Comment: @Ragul your "MyVchicle" viewcontroller not calling due to error "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0xae09430>." then why you written their??? Also why you are calling two view controller one after another??